# How to find the extra rows in a new dataframe that are not present in the older dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which was modified into a new one.

The new one now has extra rows, and I want to detect which rows are extra

I used two methods:

Method 1: setdiff() function

Method 2: comparedf()

But both of these doesn't give extra rows in the new dataframe

Comment: `base::setdiff` doesn't give a nice interface for data frames, but `dplyr::setdiff()` does. Make sure you have `dplyr` loaded before using `setdiff`.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, then I think you'll need to share a small reproducible example. `dplyr::setdiff(bigger_data, smaller_data)` should show you exactly which rows are in the bigger data but missing from the smaller data. If it doesn't work, then there must be some issue with your data, which we can't help with without seeing a bit of data...

Comment: `dput()` is the best way to share data on Stack Overflow. `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows of `your_data`, including all data structure information. If you need to share some data, please share a `dput()` of a sample of each of your data frames. Try to choose a sample that illustrates the problem - some rows in common and some not.